# Colored stacked areas are not displayed in stacked area chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below and Im trying to create a stacked area chart using `ggplot()` and `ggplotly()`. But while the chart seems to be produced without errors I cannot display the colored areas.

```
x_dt<-structure(list(interval_end = c("2021-08-14", "2021-08-14", "2021-08-14", 
"2021-08-14", "2021-08-15", "2021-08-15", "2021-08-15", "2021-08-15", 
"2021-08-16", "2021-08-16", "2021-08-16", "2021-08-16", "2021-08-17", 
"2021-08-17", "2021-08-17", "2021-08-17", "2021-08-18", "2021-08-18", 
"2021-08-18", "2021-08-18", "2021-08-19", "2021-08-19", "2021-08-19", 
"2021-08-19", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-20", 
"2021-08-21", "2021-08-21", "2021-08-21", "2021-08-21", "2021-08-22", 
"2021-08-22", "2021-08-22", "2021-08-22", "2021-08-23", "2021-08-23", 
"2021-08-23", "2021-08-23", "2021-08-24", "2021-08-24", "2021-08-24", 
"2021-08-24", "2021-08-25", "2021-08-25", "2021-08-25", "2021-08-25", 
"2021-08-26", "2021-08-26", "2021-08-26", "2021-08-26", "2021-08-27", 
"2021-08-27", "2021-08-27", "2021-08-27", "2021-08-28", "2021-08-28", 
"2021-08-28", "2021-08-28", "2021-08-29", "2021-08-29", "2021-08-29", 
"2021-08-29", "2021-08-30", "2021-08-30", "2021-08-30", "2021-08-30", 
"2021-08-15", "2021-08-15", "2021-08-15", "2021-08-15", "2021-08-16", 
"2021-08-16", "2021-08-16", "2021-08-16", "2021-08-17", "2021-08-17", 
"2021-08-17", "2021-08-17", "2021-08-18", "2021-08-18", "2021-08-18", 
"2021-08-18", "2021-08-19", "2021-08-19", "2021-08-19", "2021-08-19", 
"2021-08-20", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-21", 
"2021-08-21", "2021-08-21", "2021-08-21", "2021-08-22", "2021-08-22", 
"2021-08-22", "2021-08-22"), inv_bin = c("(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]", "(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", 
"(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]"), N = c(58L, 55L, 38L, 25L, 0L, 
9L, 13L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 13L, 5L, 44L, 120L, 69L, 48L, 17L, 103L, 
66L, 61L, 20L, 69L, 67L, 63L, 29L, 63L, 69L, 51L, 28L, 41L, 29L, 
36L, 2L, 8L, 19L, 10L, 2L, 17L, 16L, 9L, 22L, 65L, 52L, 50L, 
34L, 45L, 62L, 68L, 49L, 39L, 54L, 51L, 89L, 70L, 42L, 51L, 59L, 
105L, 59L, 65L, 3L, 24L, 23L, 16L, 45L, 36L, 18L, 13L, 58L, 64L, 
51L, 31L, 2L, 20L, 26L, 11L, 46L, 131L, 82L, 53L, 61L, 223L, 
135L, 109L, 37L, 172L, 133L, 124L, 49L, 132L, 136L, 114L, 57L, 
104L, 98L, 87L, 30L, 49L, 48L, 46L)), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))



# Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(plotly)
# Plot
p<-ggplot(x_dt, aes(x=interval_end, y=N, fill=inv_bin)) + 
    geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=.5, colour="white") +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T) +
    theme_ipsum() + 
    ggtitle("Chart 1")

ggplotly(p)
```

The result is expected to be like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of data preparation is required:

1. dates from character into date format
2. combine count `N` where there are dates and inv_bin with the same value.

```r
# Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(forcats)
library(plotly)

x_dt1 <- 
  x_dt %>% 
  mutate(interval_end = as.Date(interval_end, "%Y-%m-%d"),
         inv_bin = factor(inv_bin, levels = c("(0.0, 10.0]", "(10.0, 70.0]", "(70.0, 330.0]", "(330.0, inf]"), ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(interval_end, inv_bin) %>% 
  summarise(N = sum(N))
  
  
p <-
  ggplot(x_dt1, aes(x = interval_end, y = N, fill = fct_rev(inv_bin)))+
  geom_area(alpha = 0.6 , size = 0.5, colour = "white", stat = "identity", orientation = "x") +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  labs(fill = NULL)+
  theme_ipsum() + 
  ggtitle("Chart 1")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p

# not printed
# ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks for the answer but I would expect the result to look like more than a line chart like in the image in the edited Question